# Woocommerce: Automatically add products to cart on single category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make Woocommerce works like this:
Once user purchase something from certain category automatically I want to add one product. 
How to do that? 
This code below is automatically on visit, globally.

```
    // add item to cart on visit
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 222;
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think [Chained Products](http://www.woothemes.com/products/chained-products/) if you want them to have that product for free or [Force Sells](http://www.woothemes.com/products/force-sells/) if they would need to pay for that product.

Comment: thank you. no other free solution to solve code myself?